# ossec.conf on wazuh manager

Tags: docker, file, wazuh, ossec

I have issue with my Wazuh Manager. I want to push ossec.conf configruation on all my agent installed but I don't know how to do that.
I can modify my ossec.conf of my wazuh manager but not of my agents.
Is it possible or not ? I need to change the ossec.conf on all my agents ?

Thanks.

-Modify ossec.conf of the wazuh manager and restart it
-add information on agent.conf of my group

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late. I have already solve my problem. I just didn't understand how the agent.conf works. 
Thank you.